# Chromium - H.264 support on Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, chrome

is there a way to add H.264 support to Chromium on Fedora 23/24?

Any workaround or alternative solution is fine.

I currently use [spot's Chromium repo](https://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/spot/chromium/).

EDIT: It seems, there is currently no other option that would not require recompiling Chromium.
EDIT: Ubuntu has chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra package that adds necessary codecs. But this support has to be enabled at compilation time in Chromium.

Answer (score 3):

In fedora 26 , you can try search all package that related to Chromium by using

`sudo dnf search chromium`

Here we got some information about packages name that match Chromium.

[image]

Now the package that we need to install was

`chromium-libs-media-freeworld.x86_64`

you can check [here](https://www.youtube.com/html5) to make sure your browser successfully support H.264